# JavaScript MySql INSERT statement for multiple rows through URL

Tags: javascript, mysql, api, express, url

Good day !
I am trying to send an object array to my MySql Database through an url using an API.

Here is the code on my API :

```
app.get("/orderdetails/add", (req, res) => {
  const {
    item__,
    Qty_Ordered,
    Unit_Price,
    Ext_Price
  } = req.query;
  const INSERT_ORDERDETAILS_QUERY = `INSERT INTO oe_details (item__, 
    Qty_Ordered, Unit_Price, Ext_Price) VALUES('${item__}', '${Qty_Ordered}', 
    '${Unit_Price}', '${Ext_Price}')`;
  connection1.query(INSERT_ORDERDETAILS_QUERY, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    } else {
      return res.send("successfully added order details");
    }
  });
});
```

And below is the function on my App :

```
addOrderDetails = _ => {
  const o = this.props.o;
  const summary = o.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.Quantity >= 1;
  });
  var url = "";
  summary.forEach(function(e) {
    url +=
      "item__=" +
      e.ExternalID +
      "&Qty_Ordered=" +
      e.Quantity +
      "&Unit_Price=" +
      e.Price +
      "&Ext_Price=" +
      e.ExtPrice +
      "&";
  });
  url = url.trim("&");
  fetch(`http://localhost:4000/orderdetails/add?${url}`).catch(err =>
    console.error(err)
  );
};
```

When I run addOrderDetails, I end up sending the following statement to MySql:

```
INSERT INTO oe_details (item__, Qty_Ordered, Unit_Price, Ext_Price) 
VALUES('B-2080,B-2081', '8,5', '18.75,18.75', '150,93.75')
```

Which is wrong... is there a way for me to add multiple rows to mysql database using the same concept ?

it works fine if I only have 1 row to add...

Help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks,

Comment: Edit : o is an object array

Comment: I just want to point out that this is dangerous and not good security. This will easily make you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and others, assuming you have no check on your back-end to prevent these attacks. You should just pass the values through and on your back-end grab the values and build the SQL statement there. This way you can check the values for validation before executing the statement. In return, increasing your security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert multiple rows, MySQL statement should be like

```
INSERT INTO oe_details (item__, Qty_Ordered, Unit_Price, Ext_Price)
VALUES('B-2080,B-2081', '8,5', '18.75,18.75', '150,93.75'),
VALUES('C-2080,C-2081', '8,5', '18.75,18.75', '150,93.75'),
VALUES('B-2080,B-2081', '8,5', '18.75,18.75', '150,93.75');
```

You can change your API to a POST call and send an array of your data to it, and within your API you can form the above query.

You can use a simple for loop to create such query.

```
let summary = [1,2,3,4] // dummy data
let INSERT_ORDERDETAILS_QUERY = `INSERT INTO oe_details (item__, Qty_Ordered, Unit_Price, Ext_Price) VALUES`
summary.forEach(function(data, i) {
  INSERT_ORDERDETAILS_QUERY = `${INSERT_ORDERDETAILS_QUERY} (${data})`;
  INSERT_ORDERDETAILS_QUERY = (i !== summary.length - 1) ? `${INSERT_ORDERDETAILS_QUERY}, ` : `${INSERT_ORDERDETAILS_QUERY};`;
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes thank you. It is excatly what I am trying to do. The thing is the number of objects will vary depending on how many items were on the order. Do you have any idea how I could form the above statement ? For each object to add "Values( item, qty, price, etxprice)"

Comment: Yes, you can do it using a simple for loop. Refer to my answer above. I have edited it with the solution.